# Tell if a BasicMongoDBObject is valid from the .toString()?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'd like to confirm that a parser I wrote is working correctly. It takes a JavaScript mongodb command that could be run from the terminal and converts it to a Java object for the MongoDB/Java drivers.

Is the following .toString() result valid?

```
{ "NumShares " : 1 , "attr4 " : 1 , "symbol" : { "$regex" : "ESLR%"}}
```

This was converted from the following JavaScript

```
db.STOCK.find({ "symbol": "ESLR%" }, { "NumShares" : 1, "attr4" : 1 })
```

And of course, the data as it rests in the collections

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "538c99e41f12e5a479269ed1"} , "symbol" : "ESLR" , "NumShares" : 3471.0}
```

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You've combined the query document and the project document in that `find()` call in to one document.  That's probably not what you want.  But those documents are just json so you could use any parser to convert those.  There's a few gotchas you'd have to deal with around ObjectIDs, dates, DBRefs, and particularly regular expressions but those can be managed without too much trouble by escaping/quoting them before parsing.

Comment: The separate query conditions are represented as documents which are then 'put' into a master query object. The first code block is the result of the toString() of the final query object. Does it look correct?

Comment: To me, it looks wrong to have both docs put in to one, but I'm not sure how your code will use it.  But otherwise looks fine.